# number of distinct regions in the binary image (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, gd

I have b/w image spited into 4 segments. I need to know **how many** regions are there at each segment.

Here is an example with better explanation.
[image: ocr]

I am wondering **if there is ready-made API** available for this in any of most popular c++ image processing libraries? ( like **gd, cimg, opencv**?)

Comment: I guess you could choose a random point and floodfill. Check if all pixels are black or the floodedcolour, if not, choose another random, uncoloured point and flood fill with another colour. Repeat till there are no uncoloured pixels whilst counting how many iterations are needed.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to choose a random pixel, it could just as easily be deterministic and you could scan from the top-left corner across and down.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am looking for complete solution from some of the available image processing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use **OpenCV**'s `connectedComponents()` and the answer you seek is one less than the number it returns:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc!=2){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Please supply an image name" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }

    // Load up the image and check
    Mat image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if(image.empty()){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to load image" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }

    // Calculate connected components
    Mat label;
    int n=connectedComponents(image,label,8,CV_16U);
    std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;
}
```

[image]

Returns 5.

---

[image]

Returns 4.

---

[image]

Returns 3.

---

[image]

Returns 3.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I got incorrect answer for this image. https://ibb.co/iAW0Va

 I've extended your code with slicing image into small regions https://codepaste.net/pbnjm6


p.s. sorry for the mess hit save too soon.

Comment: What answer did you get? What images did you use?

Comment: here is the image I got from the first slice. https://ibb.co/iLAAVa
you can see regions are 2, but instead _italic_ connectedComponents-1 _italic_ say it's 1.

Comment: It's late here in the UK, so I will look again tomorrow. Please maybe try a couple of very simple images with one, then two distinct squares or circles in them to see if you can isolate the error. Also maybe try black lines on a white background the same as your question implied - so I mean to threshold your image to pure black and white first.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's happening - the lines are thinner than I expected from the examples and that allows the floodfill to flow through the lines thereby joining two regions which should be separate. Can you try with slightly fatter lines, or do a morphological dilation on them to see if that helps?

Comment: Or change the 8 to a 4 in `connectedComponents()`.

Comment: I had a quick check, your new image is not binary as your question states - please run a binary `threshold()` before calling `connectedComponents()` and it works fine.